# AnimateChild does not work for child :leave transition

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

I have angular `"@angular/animations": "^4.3.0"` installed in my project and i'm trying to run a childAnimation().

I two animations, one for a parent and one for a child element. Both with :enter and :leave transitions. The parent element is displayed depending on `*ngIf="isOpen"`.

> :enter works on both elements but :leave is not animated on the child element

In order to do this i've read that i have to use `query('@*', animateChild())`. The problem is this still does not work. Is there anything i'm missing here? My guess is that :leave is not working on the child as only the parent is triggered with *ngIf, but how can i trigger a :leave transition on the child then?

template:

```
<div *ngIf="isOpen" [@fadeAnimation] (click)="close()">
    <div [@slideHorizontalAnimation] (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

animations:

```
export const fadeAnimation = trigger(
    'fadeAnimation',
    [
        transition(
            ':enter',
            [
                style({ opacity: 0 }),
                animate('100ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))
            ]
        ),
        transition(
            ':leave',
            [
                style({ opacity: 1 }),
                animate('100ms', style({ opacity: 0 })),
                query('@*', animateChild())
            ]
        )
    ]
);

export const slideHorizontalAnimation = trigger(
    'slideHorizontalAnimation',
    [
        transition(
            ':enter',
            [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }),
                animate('100ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
            ]
        ),
        transition(
            ':leave',
            [
                style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }),
                animate('100ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }))
            ]
        )
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15798

> [Animation] In Angular4, leave (* -> void) animation doesn't fire when element is destroyed by ngIf value change

and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15753

> Leave animation not running in a nested animation of a child component

Even if one them appear to be closed, some people seem to think it's not. The second one is still opened

UPDATE : It might be fixed by https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19006 which is not yet merged

Comment: That's why i added animateChild() as described in a comment in your first link, but that didn't work. I actually got it to work when i added the `*ngIf="isOpen"` to both elements, parent and child, but that seems more like a workaround.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19006 might fix it and make it work as expected, we juste have to wait for the merge and hope ;)

Answer (score -1):

This one works for me:

```
export const routerAnimation = [
  trigger('routeAnimation', [
    transition('* => *', [
      group([
        query(':leave', [animate('1s', style({}))]),  // animate's timings should bigger than the child's :leave animation. With this, the leaving component doesn't removed directly from DOM
        query('@*', animateChild()),
      ]),
    ]),
  ]),
];
```